# Adding onclick function on a dynamically added table row

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a page which displays records in a table and I am able to do that but after adding a code so a highlighted table row will change color, I am now getting error instead.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE `Main Type`='main1' AND `DB Type`='Active' ORDER BY `Record ID`");

echo "<table border='1' style='width:100%; font-family:arial,Serif;font-style:regular;font-size:12px; color:black' CELLPADDING='1' CELLSPACING='0'>
<tr>
<th>Record ID</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>City</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>Zip Code</th>
<th>County</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Bed</th>
<th>Bath</th>
<th>Square Foot</th>
<th>Year Built</th>
<th>As Is Value</th>
<th>DB Type</th>
<th>Main Type</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr onclick='toggle(this)'>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Record ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['City'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['State'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Zip Code'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['County'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Price'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Bed'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Bath'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Square Foot'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Year Built'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['As Is Value'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['DB Type'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Main Type'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table><br>";

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "function toggle(it) { if ((it.style.backgroundColor == 'none') || (it.style.backgroundColor == '')){it.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';}}";
echo "</script>"


mysqli_close($con);
```

Basically my main goal is if the user clicks on a row, the entire row will change color to indicate it is being selected. My more advance goal is a mousemove instead of onclick. I'm looking for the easiest and less complicated way to do this, I have this feeling that the solution is simple. I hope you guys can help.

The error I'm getting is

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/u560877965/public_html/hud.php on line 59

Comment: Where is line 59? Could you specify, please?

Comment: `echo "</script>"` < add a semicolon `;` here.

Comment: Do you know you don't have to `echo "blah"; echo "blah"; echo "blah";`  and can just use a new line for readability? `echo "<tr onclick='toggle(this)'> [new line] <td>" . $row['Record ID'] . "</td> [new line]...`

Comment: Hello @popnoodles, I think you have a shorter, simpler suggestion, can I get more info on what you are trying to suggest? I'm a beginner in php by the way, I'm a VB Programmer but I need this done with php/javascript.

Comment: My comment doesn't answer the question, though it might have prevented the problem. See how your first chunk of echo just uses new lines, not echo echo echo, that's much tidier. http://oi42.tinypic.com/bgrcep.jpg

Comment: oh ok I got it now, thanks :) I do like it in series of echo however, I'm not sure why but when debugging I find that easier to read/understand than one liners

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed semicolon from after string in code.

Change this:

```
echo "</script>"
```

to this:

```
echo "</script>";
//              ^ here (for those who can't see it)
```

Comment: so what is the difference between to echo  ?

Comment: ahh sory i miss the semicolon :)

Comment: Ahhh back to the old days, programming.. debugging... where a single speck of dust can fail the entire program.:) Thanks much guys